# Url routing in elgg

Tags: url-rewriting, social-networking, elgg

I am trying to create a social network application using elgg.Since i am pretty new to elgg i like know whether i can define url routing like in **cakePHP**

I need the url like this 
mydomain.com/username instead of mydomin.com/pg/profile/username

Is there any way that i can avoid /pg/ and /mod/ from the urls??

I am using elgg version 1.7.8.

**I am not interested in url rewriting with `.htaccess`.**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elgg itself is using `.htaccess` file to redirect `/pg`, `/action` etc. So, I think there is no other way than using `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

Elgg's page handling is pretty bad but you can register handlers as follows.

for /mypage:

```
    elgg_register_page_handler('mypage', function($pages){
        //content here
        //the $pages parameter is an array. so /mypage/a/b with return
        // array('a','b');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Matt Beckett has written a profile URL plugin (https://community.elgg.org/plugins/1091233) that, though for 1.8 and above, is only 35 lines of code and does exactly what you ask. You should be able to adapt this quite easily for 1.7.8.

He has also written a fuller page handler hijack plugin that may help if you have other use cases apart from user profiles - see https://community.elgg.org/plugins/854839

It is also only for 1.8 and above, however, and may take more effort to backport than the first.